# React Native put a "Cooldown" on a Button

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, button, textinput

my question is if it is possible to put a cooldown on a button that the user presses, or to only register like 1 press in 2 seconds. I am using React Native (Expo) connected with a REST API and a PostgreSQL DB.

My problem is that I have a Button that sends data to a Database. OnPress the entered Values are PUT to the database and the User gets navigated to another Screen where he can see his entry.

I noticed that when a user is fast enought he can press the button twice or 3 times and therefore the data also is posted 2/3 times to the db.

I would need something like one second cooldown so the data is only posted 1 time because the navigation almost happens immediatly!

I could not find anything in the internet on this.

Thanks ~Faded

Comment: A million ways to do it - remove the `onPress` after the button has been pressed, set a disabled property after it has been pressed, etc etc. This is like the old days of the internet, "please only press the submit button once"

Comment: @Adam I cant remove the onPress or set it disabled because if a user enters the screen again he obviouslly wants to continue to use the form and button like before so a cooldown timer would be perfect of like 1 or 2 seconds thats enough.

Comment: That's the absolute wrong way to do it - what if the PUT takes longer than 1 or 2 seconds? In reality, you want to disable the button UNTIL the PUT is complete.

Comment: well you might be right I could either show a spinner in that time or disable the button in the beginning of the function and enable it at the end maybe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the button disabled as soon as it's pressed.

```js
const MyComponent = ({makePutCall}) => {
   const [disabled,setDisabled] = useState(false);

   const doPut = async () => {
       setDisabled(true);
       await makePutCall();
       setDisabled(false);
   }

   return <Button disabled={disabled} onPress={doPut}/>
 
}
```

or use a ref to prevent pushing more than once:

```js
const MyComponent = ({makePutCall}) => {
   const disabled = useRef(false);

   const doPut = async () => {
       if(disabled.current) return;
       disabled.current = true;
       await makePutCall();
       disabled.current = false;
   }

   return <Button onPress={doPut}/>
 
}
```

My person favourite is a spinner, like you said:

```js
const MyComponent = ({makePutCall}) => {
   const [showSpinner,setShowSpinner] = useState(false);

   const handlePress = async () => {
      setShowSpinner(true);
      await makePutCall();
      setShowSpinner(false);
   }

   return showSpinner ? <Spinner/> : <Button onPress={handlePress}/>
}
```

or do it another way - DON'T USE A TIMER.

Comment: Yeah I just implemented a Spinner on the Button - pretty easy I guess and its efficient!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 solutions I can think of as of now, there might be many other solution as well.

**Solution 1:**
Have some variable which can keep a value if database call has already been done, once you get response from database you can reset that variable and user can press that button again.

Something like

```
onPress = {this.state.isPressed ? null : <this.writeTodatabase>}
```

and

```
writeTodatabase = () => {
    this.setState({ isPressed:true })
    // code to write to database
    // once you have response from database you can set isPressed to false.
}
```

You can also disable button if that variable is true.

**Solution 2:** You can use `throttle` from `lodash` library.

[Reference Document](https://lodash.com/docs/#throttle)

Answer (score 0):

try using [debounce](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#debounce)/[throttle](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#throttle). here is a basic example of debounce.

```
Import * as _ from lodash;
...
...

      
onPressDebounced = _.debounce(this.onPressed(),500);

render() { 
  return ( 
    <TouchableHighlight 
      { ...this.props } 
      onPress = { this.onPressDebounced}> 
      {this.props.children} 
    </TouchableHighlight>
  )
}
```

Comment: debounce/throttle is the wrong way to handle this - there is a **known** time when the button should become re-enabled - when the response has been returned from the server.

Comment: @Adam Agreed! But, the problem needs to stop multiple clicks and the user also redirects to a new screen immediately after it. I the case was different to wait until the API return response, we could use simple async await to complete the task!