# react native I want to prevent duplicate clicks in native

Tags: javascript, react-native

I want to prevent two windows from opening when quickly clicking a button with different links.
Is there any way?

```js
<View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.groupName}>
            <Text style={styles.navMenu}>{menusTitle}</Text>
        </View>
        {menus.map((menus ,i)=>{
          return(
            <Text key={i} accessibilityRole='button' style={styles.navDetailMenu} 
              onPress={() => props.navigation.navigate(menus.name)}>{menus.title}</Text> 
          )
        })}
        
    </View>
```

Comment: Refer [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64008592/react-native-put-a-cooldown-on-a-button/64008747#64008747), it is something related to what you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use props disabled , disable after first click.